# Ошибка при указании свойства зависимости в Storyboard

Tags: c#, xaml, анимация, windows-phone-8

Здравствуйте! Почему метод

```
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(this Timeline animation, new PropertyPath(propertyPath))
```

когда вызываешь в WinRT требует, чтобы `propertyPath` был строкой пути к свойству, которое необходимо анимировать и выдает такую вот ошибку (не шпрехаю на английском):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а в Silverlite-приложении работает на ура, но просит чтобы `propertyPath` был обьектом. Возможно ли как-нибудь запустить этот метод в WinRT?